# .focus() a un tabIndex

Tags: jquery, html

No encuentro la forma de hacer con `jquery` un .focus() a un elemento con la propiedad tabindex.

He visto que en las versiones antiguas de jquery no se puede, pero,  ¿actualmente esto sigue siendo asi?

¿Como puede ser que una libreria enfocada al DOM no tengas acceso a esta propiedad del HTML?

Comment: Has probado con `$('[tabindex=1]').on('focus', function() { //TODO });`

Comment: as triunfao, ponlo como respuesta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prueba con esto:

```
$('[tabindex=1]').on('focus', function() { //TODO });
```